# Unless I set the height in my iframe the width is not going 100%

Tags: css, wordpress, html, iframe, html5-canvas

I am using an iframe on a WordPress website to display an html5 animation but unless I set the height of the iframe it reduces the width.

Can anyone help me fix this? I have tried a multitude of things to fix it but no scroll is coming up so I can get 100% width, it just reduces the width.

https://tempart.posabilities.co.uk/our-story/

I think there is a conflict in my animation code:

```
<div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:960px; height:1615px">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="1615" style="position: absolute; display: none; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
    <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:960px; height:1615px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id='_preload_div_' style='position:absolute; top:0; display: inline-block;  width: 960px; text-align: center;'>    <span style='display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'></span>  <img src=images/_preloader.gif style='vertical-align: middle; max-height: 100%'/></div>
```

I was also trying to get the animation to progress on scroll but got completely lost on that!

Answer (score 0):

this is yours;

```
    #artkiframeHolder {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

make it like this

```
#artkiframeHolder {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Thanks for that I think there is a conflict in my animation code. I've added to my orginal coment at the top.